# I can't disable headers or footers in Monotouch UITableViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm using the 'IOS Table View Controller' template. The default overrides have TitleForHeader and TitleForFooter set the titles to 'Header' and 'Footer' respectively. From what I understand if you use those methods then defaults for the header and footer views are used.

I've removed those overrides there are still spaces where the headers and footers should be. I've overridden GetViewForHeader and GetViewForFooter to return null, and HeightForHeader/Footer to return zero and the spaces remain.  I've even tried creating a UIView with zero height and width and returning that, along with setting the header or footer height to zero and the spaces remain.

Is there any way to tell Monotouch to not use a header or footer?

Comment: This should work.  I would try deleting all the header/footer override methods since you do not need them.

Comment: I did that. The only one that was there by default was 'TitleForFooter'. Removing that removed the footer, but left a small space. I did find that adding this in viewDidLoad removed the extra space:`this.TableView.SectionFooterHeight = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding this in viewDidLoad removed the extra space:

```
this.TableView.SectionFooterHeight = 0;
```